# Xfinity app for iOS, odd info listed for "app version"

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, ios-appstore, xcode

My Xfinity app has been problematic for over a year with multiple errors when trying to change my password, view customer info like data usage or call history, and paying my bill.

The specific errors I get are blank pages or messages: "something isn't working" and "oops something went wrong"

When I try to pay my bill it will show me a page that says I don't have permission to access "xfinity.com/payments"

Apple keeps telling me to go to Xfinity who keep telling me to go to Apple.

Xfinity general customer service have no idea how to support issues within the app and it's been a struggle to get help beyond delete/reinstall. I have deleted and reinstalled the app many times as well as reformatted and getting a new phone didn't change the errors.

Here is a screenshot of what I'm seeing in the app settings:
https://ibb.co/ZxjxQf6

The old iPhone is a 14 Pro Max and this description for the app version never showed up on that phone.

The new iPhone is a 15+ and that's where I'm seeing this app version info. Both are updated to iOS 17.4.1

I'm just trying to understand this info in the app settings while I continue to try to get someone at Xfinity who can troubleshot.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Apple can’t assist you; only Xfinity can. The fact you are being told to talk to Apple is just the first level support person getting you off their line.  The app is faulty, stop using it and do your transactions via the web.

Comment: The only thing you can do yourself is to delete and reinstall the app. That will cause its data to be recreated.

Comment: I am seeking info on the description in the screenshot and only described the errors in case they're related. 

The app is necessary to manage WiFi network access and devices using WiFi so it can't simply be deleted.